# javascript/react/redux async await refactoring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, refactoring

I would like to refactor the `fetchRelationships` function to use async await. I am not sure what the best way is to do it as this code contains nested `.then` at `response.json().then((json) =>...`.

Could sby pls post the refactored version?

```
export const fetchRelationshipsError = (error) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_RELATIONSHIPS_FAILURE,
    payload: { error }
  };
};

export const fetchRelationshipsRequest = () => {
  return { type: FETCH_RELATIONSHIPS_REQUEST };
};

export const fetchRelationshipsSuccess = (relationships) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_RELATIONSHIPS_SUCCESS,
    payload: relationships
  };
};

export const fetchRelationships = (url) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchRelationshipsRequest());

    fetch(url, config)
    .then((response) => {
      const responseObj = {
        response: response,
        payload: response.json().then((json) => {
          return { body: json }
        })
      };

      if (!response.ok) {
        const error = new Error(response.statusText);
        responseObj.payload.then((response) => {
          show_error_alert(response.body);
          dispatch(fetchRelationshipsError(response.body));
        });
        throw error;
      }

      return responseObj.payload;
    })
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch(fetchRelationshipsSuccess(response.body))
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log('Request failed', error); });
  };
};
```

Solution:

```
export const fetchRelationships = (url) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchRelationshipsRequest());

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, config);
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();

      if (!response.ok) {
        show_error_alert(jsonResponse);
        dispatch(fetchRelationshipsError(jsonResponse));

        const error = new Error(response.statusText);
        throw error;
      }

      dispatch(fetchRelationshipsSuccess(jsonResponse));

    } catch(error) {
      console.log('Request failed', error);
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Ill take a stab at this:

```
export const fetchRelationshipsError = (error) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_RELATIONSHIPS_FAILURE,
    payload: { error }
  };
};

export const fetchRelationshipsRequest = () => {
  return { type: FETCH_RELATIONSHIPS_REQUEST };
};

export const fetchRelationshipsSuccess = (relationships) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_RELATIONSHIPS_SUCCESS,
    payload: relationships
  };
};

export const fetchRelationships = (url) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {

    dispatch(fetchRelationshipsRequest());

    try{

      const response = await fetch(url, config)
      const jsonResponse = await response.json()

      if(!response.ok){

        show_error_alert(jsonResponse);
        dispatch(fetchRelationshipsError(jsonResponse));

        const error = new Error(response.statusText);
        throw error;
      }

      dispatch(fetchRelationshipsSuccess(jsonResponse));

    }catch(error){
      console.log('Request failed', error);
    }  

  };
```

Comment: It says await is a reserved keyword. (I added the async as well.)

Comment: Oh I'll edit the code one sec. Added Async in-front of the return function (dispatch)

Comment: Spencer, I solved it based on your ideas. I added the solution to my question. Your code includes a few mistakes including the extra `async`. If you change it based on my solution, I will accept your answer.